# $m^n$ has exactly $9$ digits, all of these digits are distinct.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, exponentiation, natural-numbers, perfect-powers

I was reading the following problem in a book: $2^{29}$ has exactly $9$ digits, all of these digits are distinct, what is the missing digit?

I tried to solve it, and I did it correctly.

---

Suddenly, the following two questions popped into my mind:

- Find the number of pairs of natural numbers $m$ and $n$ $(n \ne 1)$ such that $m^n$ has exactly $9$ digits, all of these digits are distinct.
- Find the least $9$-digit number that can be expressed as $m^n$ where $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers and $n \ne 1$.

---

These questions may be solved using a software, but I am not sure if we can use a purely mathematical way.

Do not provide a solution. I am just asking for useful hints/formulae/techniques, then I will try to solve them.

---

Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Comment: How did you solve the case $2^{29}$ ?

Comment: Digits are essentially random, there is no known connection between "all digits are distinct" and other properties of a number. So I don't see another option than to check all eligible powers one by one. I wouldn't want to do that manually, but a computer wouldn't find it hard, I guess.

Comment: I agree with @ProfessorVector - there's really no reason to expect any sort of general connection when digits are so closely tied to their base. Unless you're maybe looking at a base (for the exponent) with some sort of "special relationship" with $10$ (and it's not even clear what such a "special relationship" would be), there's really unlikely to be any general connection of the type you're looking for. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

My computer says:
$$10124^{2}=102495376$$
$$10128^{2}=102576384$$
$$10136^{2}=102738496$$
$$10214^{2}=104325796$$
$$10278^{2}=105637284$$
$$11826^{2}=139854276$$
$$12363^{2}=152843769$$
$$12543^{2}=157326849$$
$$12582^{2}=158306724$$
$$12586^{2}=158407396$$
$$13147^{2}=172843609$$
$$13268^{2}=176039824$$
$$13278^{2}=176305284$$
$$13343^{2}=178035649$$
$$13434^{2}=180472356$$
$$13545^{2}=183467025$$
$$13698^{2}=187635204$$
$$14098^{2}=198753604$$
$$14442^{2}=208571364$$
$$14676^{2}=215384976$$
$$14743^{2}=217356049$$
$$14766^{2}=218034756$$
$$15353^{2}=235714609$$
$$15681^{2}=245893761$$
$$15963^{2}=254817369$$
$$16549^{2}=273869401$$
$$16854^{2}=284057316$$
$$17252^{2}=297631504$$
$$17529^{2}=307265841$$
$$17778^{2}=316057284$$
$$17816^{2}=317409856$$
$$18072^{2}=326597184$$
$$19023^{2}=361874529$$
$$19377^{2}=375468129$$
$$19569^{2}=382945761$$
$$19629^{2}=385297641$$
$$20089^{2}=403567921$$
$$20316^{2}=412739856$$
$$20513^{2}=420783169$$
$$20754^{2}=430728516$$
$$21397^{2}=457831609$$
$$21439^{2}=459630721$$
$$21744^{2}=472801536$$
$$21801^{2}=475283601$$
$$21877^{2}=478603129$$
$$21901^{2}=479653801$$
$$22175^{2}=491730625$$
$$22456^{2}=504271936$$
$$22887^{2}=523814769$$
$$23019^{2}=529874361$$
$$23113^{2}=534210769$$
$$23178^{2}=537219684$$
$$23439^{2}=549386721$$
$$23682^{2}=560837124$$
$$23728^{2}=563017984$$
$$23889^{2}=570684321$$
$$24009^{2}=576432081$$
$$24237^{2}=587432169$$
$$24276^{2}=589324176$$
$$24441^{2}=597362481$$
$$24807^{2}=615387249$$
$$25059^{2}=627953481$$
$$25279^{2}=639027841$$
$$25572^{2}=653927184$$
$$25941^{2}=672935481$$
$$26152^{2}=683927104$$
$$26351^{2}=694375201$$
$$26409^{2}=697435281$$
$$26733^{2}=714653289$$
$$27105^{2}=734681025$$
$$27129^{2}=735982641$$
$$27209^{2}=740329681$$
$$27273^{2}=743816529$$
$$27984^{2}=783104256$$
$$28171^{2}=793605241$$
$$28256^{2}=798401536$$
$$28346^{2}=803495716$$
$$28582^{2}=816930724$$
$$28731^{2}=825470361$$
$$29034^{2}=842973156$$
$$29106^{2}=847159236$$
$$29208^{2}=853107264$$
$$30384^{2}=923187456$$
$$2^{29}=536870912$$
So there are quite a few squares and just one higher power with that property.

Comment: I was looking for a purely mathematical way, without using a software, but it seems that there is no way. I just thought that these two questions are interested. Thank you very much for providing this. Your answer may be helpful to verify my solution (If I could solve). (+1)